# How does one handle file type changes in Perforce?

Tags: encoding, perforce

When you add a file to Perforce, it attempts to determine what type of file it is (text, binary, utf16, etc.).  It's does a good job of this, but apparently never checks the file type again after the initial submission to version control.  A coworker recently made a change to a text file that converted it to Unicode (utf16).  Perforce didn't recognize this and still considered it type *text*, so when others retrieved the file, it was corrupt.

We fixed the problem by resubmitting the file and explicitly changing the file type to *utf16*, but would prefer if this happened automatically.  There are ways to force it to always use a certain encoding type, but I don't know if I like that idea.  Has anyone dealt with, and found a solution to, this problem?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Perforce tech support had this to say:

> Perforce does not check the content of
>   the file when you submit an edit.
>
> Checking every single file edit for
>   content is potentially very expensive.
>   "text" and "utf16" are not the only
>   file types to look out for, a file
>   could potentially change type from
>   "text" to "binary" for example.
>
> Another problem is that sometimes a
>   user wants to override the default
>   behavior of how Perforce recognizes a
>   file. How should the server react in
>   this case if the actual file type does
>   not match the file type the user
>   provides?
>
> For these reasons Perforce will only
>   determine the file type when the file
>   is added, and take the "typemap" and
>   the command parameter "-t" into
>   account.
>
> On the other hand, you can prevent
>   your situation from happening again by
>   employing a "change-content" trigger.
>   This trigger would check the content
>   of the file and compare it to the
>   specified file type, rejecting any
>   submit that creates a mismatch.

Comment: Can anyone point to how to do that? I'm not familiar with triggers or examining the content for text type.